# Calculate the N IP of a network

Tags: python, networking, ip

I would like to know which N IP of a given network my IP is.

For example 192.168.0.3 is the 3 IP of the network 192.168.0.0/20.
The 256 IP would be 192.168.1.0

Is there a way to calculate this very fast in python? I know about ipcalc but that does not has any option like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [`ipaddress`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ipaddress) module in the standard library, a Network object can be used as a iterable of Addresses. So, this is just a normal find in a sequence:

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> addr = ipaddress.ip_address('192.168.0.1')
>>> net = ipaddress.ip_network('192.168.0.0/20')
>>> net[256]
IPv4Address('192.168.1.0')
>>> next(i for i, a in enumerate(net) if a == addr)
3
```

See the [HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/ipaddress.html#ipaddress-howto) for more explanation.

Note that this works fine for addresses in integer form as well as dotted strings, for IPv6 as well as IPv4, etc.

If you're using Python 2.x, you'll need the [backport on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipaddress). If you're using 3.0-3.2, I believe the backport doesn't yet support those, in which case the best bet is to use the library it was based on, [`ipaddr`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipaddr) instead.

Comment: that is also a possible way but the problem is that it is not very fast. try to calculate a 10/8 and it will eat up all your memory

Comment: @DennyCrane: No it won't. A generator expression over an iterable doesn't eat up any memory.

Comment: oh yes, sorry. i missread it. my bad

Answer (score 1):

```
reduce(lambda x,y: (int(x)*256)+int(y), IP.split('.')[2:])

>>> IP = "192.168.0.3"
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: (int(x)*256)+int(y), IP.split('.')[2:])
3
>>> IP = "192.168.1.0"
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: (int(x)*256)+int(y), IP.split('.')[2:])
256
```

As @Blake points out, you can make this even more versatile with an added parameter:

```
def versatileCount(IP, b):
    return reduce(lambda x,y: (int(x)*256)+int(y), IP.split('.')[-b:])

>>> def versatileCount(IP, b):
...     if not 1 <= b <= 4:
...         raise ValueError("b has to be between 1 and 4")
...     return reduce(lambda x,y: (int(x)*256)+int(y), IP.split('.')[-b:])
...
>>> versatileCount(IP,2)
256
>>> IP = "192.168.0.3"
>>> versatileCount(IP,2)
3
```

Comment: Clever. The only thing I would change is making the reduce(...) inside another lambda that takes a parameter that specifics how many indices of the IP to include (4-1).

Comment: thx a lot! exactly what i was searching for :)

Comment: This only works if your network is a /24 (or, for the versatile version, a /16 or /8). It won't work for, e.g., a /20. Which was exactly what the original question asked for.